# What does sentence[:] mean here?

Tags: python

I'm study Learnpythonthehardway, in ex40, I met this slice of code.

```
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result = sentence[:]
```

I'm not quite understanding sentence[:] here, especially the [:]

I've tried to figure it out by underlying test code:

```
sentence = 'sss errf : fe : eee'
f = 33
result = sentence[:f]
print result
```

but nothing happens, result is the same as the sentence

So, smart geeks, what does sentence[:] mean here?

Comment: As explained by @inclement, `[:]` is used for lists, but in this exercise `sentence` is a string so I don't see why he used `[:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a use of python's list slice syntax that simply means 'copy the whole list'.

You might often do something like `some_list[:5]` to get the first 5 elements, or `some_list[5:]` to get everything from the fifth element onwards (or sixth element onwards if you count the zeroth as the first, since python lists are zero-indexed). If you think like that, it's natural that the syntax means everything from the first element to the last one.

An important thing here is that this does produce a *copy* of the list, not a reference to the original list. That means it can be a useful way to clone a list, it doesn't just do nothing.

Comment: Another important note is that alhtough it produces a copy of the list, it may still contain references, not copies, of sublists. To avoid this, use `copy.deepcopy`.